# How to avoid re computation in spark Dataset?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, rdd

I am new to Spark. I am doing data transformation, grouping using spark. Re-computation is happening multiple times. I want your suggestions to avoid re-computation

Sample Input: Json Array

```
[{ "id": 1, "filepath": "/tmp/file1.xml" }, { "id": 2, "filepath": "/tmp/file2.xml" }]
```

Sample File content:

```
<xml><key>1</key><value>2</value></xml>
```

Flow:

1. Load files

`JavaPairRDD<String,String> textFile = sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("/tmp/file1.xml,/tmp/file2.xml");`

2. Transform Files
   //TransformerData() make API calls to transform file from XML to JSON

`JavaPairRDD<String,String> transformedOutput = textFile.flatMapToPair(TransformerData());`

Sample Transformed Data

`{ "key": 1, "value": 1 }`

> Success case: Return filename as first argument and parsed record as
> second argument
> **Sample record <"file1.xml", "{ "key": 1, "value":1 }">**
>
> Failure case:(If There is any issue happens in the file
> transformation) Return 'failed' string prefixed filename as first
> argument and null second argument
> **Sample record <"failed_file1.xml", null>**

3. Filter failed records

`JavaPairRDD<String,String> failedOutput = transformedOutput.filter((Function<Tuple2<String, String>, Boolean>) v1 -> v1._1.startsWith("failed"));`

4. Update DB and exist if there is a failed record

> ```
> if (failedOutput.count() > 0) {
>     UpdateDB();
>     throw new Exception("Parsing failed.");
> }
> ```

5. If there is no failed record then form CustomRecord RDD

`JavaRDD<CustomRecord> customRecords = GeCustomRecordRDD(transformedOutput);`

> ```
> class CustomRecord {
>   private String fileName;
>   private String key;
>   private String record;
> }
> ```

6. Create DataFrame in order to group the records

`Dataset<Row> customRecordsDataSet = spark.createDataFrame(customRecords, CustomRecord.class);`

7. Group the dataset based on the key

> ```
> Dataset<Row> groupedDataSet = customRecordsDataSet.orderBy(customRecordsDataSet.col("fileName"))
> .groupBy(customRecordsDataSet.col("key"))
> .agg(
>   functions.collect_list(customRecordsDataSet.col("record"))
> )
> ```

8. Loop the dataset to publish each key record to kafka

> ```
> groupedDataSet.foreach(new ForeachFunction<Row>() {
>     public void call(Row r) throws Exception {
>         publishMessage(FormMessage(r.get(0), r.get(1)));
>     }
> });
> ```

**Grouped Record**
1: [1,2]
Here 1 is the key in the file, 1, 2 are values. Grouped the record based on key.

Here computations happening at 3 time

- During failedOutput.count() - once
- During groupedDataSet.foreach -
  twice

I want to avoid the duplicate computation while looping groupedDataSet. There is no change in the record

Comment: I don't see how computation is duplicated..

Comment: Gosh, move to Scala. No idea why people persist with java and Big Data.

Comment: @jack when i am looping the groupedDataSet, it is getting executed twice

```20/12/16 19:20:21 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: foreach at TestUtils.java:42
20/12/16 19:20:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (foreach at TestUtils.java:42) with 1 output partitions
20/12/16 19:20:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (foreach at TestUtils.java:42)
20/12/16 19:20:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
20/12/16 19:20:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()```